# using ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum to save photo in specific Album

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6.3

I'm using XCode 6.3 and Swift 1.2 and when runing the code:

```
ALAssetsLibrary().saveImage(screenshot, toAlbum: "myAlbum", completion:nil, failure:nil)
```

I get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ALAssetsLibrary saveImage:toAlbum:completion:failure:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I use a bridging header to link the Objective C code with Swift

In the build phases I added the MobileCoreService and the AssetsLibrary framework

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

ALAssetsLibrary().saveImage(screenshot, toAlbum: "myAlbum", completion:nil, failure:nil)

Do provide `selector` for the `function`. i.e.,"`myAlbum:`